# Parsing JSON Alamofire 4.request

Tags: json, request, swift3, alamofire

I have an old piece of code with Alamofire request:

```
func downloadItemDetails (completed:DownloadComplete) {
    let url = _itemUrl!
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (request:NSURLRequest?, response:HTTPURLResponse?, result:Result<AnyObject>) -> Void in
        print(result.value.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

**How should i change the code to make it work with Alamofire 4 and Swift 3?**

p.s. I know about the changes *NSURLRequest -> URLRequest* and *NSHTTPURLResponse -> HTTPURLResponse*, also i have read Alamofire 4.0 Migration Guide, but it does not helped me.

Comment: It's always good to demonstrate research and convey what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 1):

After detailed understanding of the Alamofire migration documentation i have already solved the issue by myself:

```
func downloadItemDetails (completed:DownloadComplete) {

    let url = _itemUrl!
    Alamofire.request(url, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
}
```

Thank you for attention.
I hope it will help someone.